# how to multiply a range of elements in a line by a constat

Tags: bash, bc

I have a file with several columns and I want to multiply by a constant the first half elements of these columns over a range of lines.
For example, if I had only 4 columns and 2 lines:

```
 8  2 4 5
 6 12 8 8
```

The output I want (supposing the multiplicative constant is `1/2`) would be the following:

```
4 1 4 5
3 6 8 8
```

I have no glue how to do it, I suppose that  `bc` will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this for processing your file on row/col basis:

```
awk -v n=2 '{for (i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) $i/=n} 1' file
4 1 4 5
3 6 8 8
```